# Запись чисел в файл с разделением

Tags: c#, файлы

День добрый, требуется записать в файл 5 чисел. Вопрос в том, как эти числа, считываемые с TextBox разделить запятой и вывести на новую строку в файл.
У меня вышло лишь записать просто числа, но походу с разделением я ошибаюсь.
Пример, вводим:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Вывод:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

---

```
string writepath = @"numbers.txt";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(writepath);
try
{
     using (StreamWriter sw = file.AppendText())
     {
       string[] s = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
       sw.WriteLine("\r\n" + s + "\r\n");
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
       MessageBox.Show("Ошибка" + ex);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",\r\n", s);
```

Оказывается, все наоборот:

```
string[] parts = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ',' });
foreach(string s in parts)
{
  sw.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: а как их выводить на новую строку?

Comment: @PaulGreengod Не экономьте буквы. Что значит "выводить их на новую строку". Они уже выведены на новую строку - все на одну. Добавьте в вопрос пример ввода и ожидаемого вывода.

Comment: добавил в вопрос пример